# jupyter lab notebook SQL output wrapping

Tags: apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am new to Jupyter notebook and this is on Jupyter LAB. While executing PySpark SQL query, the output is getting wrapped around.
In the classic Jupyter notebook, the following html code help to get the data in tabular format. Is there a way to have the similar functionality in notebook on LAB.

```
%%html <style> div.output_area pre {white-space: pre;} </style>
```

Thanks
Manoj George

Comment: Does `<style> .jp-OutputArea pre {white-space: pre;} </style>` work?

Comment: Thanks @krassowski, The following lines of code did the job.

from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-OutputArea pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))